# pandas: conditionally return a column's value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a new column called 'wage_rate' that fills in the appropriate wage rate for the employee based on the year of the observation.

In other words, my list looks something like this:

```
eecode  year    w2011   w2012   w2013
1       2012    7       8       9
1       2013    7       8       9
2       2011    20      25      25
2       2012    20      25      25
2       2013    20      25      25
```

And I want return, in a new column, 8 for the first row, 9 for the second, 20, 25, 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use `apply` by constructing column name for each row based on year like `'w' + str(x.year)`.

```
In [41]: df.apply(lambda x: x['w' + str(x.year)], axis=1)
Out[41]:
0     8
1     9
2    20
3    25
4    25
dtype: int64
```

Details:

```
In [42]: df
Out[42]:
   eecode  year  w2011  w2012  w2013
0       1  2012      7      8      9
1       1  2013      7      8      9
2       2  2011     20     25     25
3       2  2012     20     25     25
4       2  2013     20     25     25

In [43]: df['wage_rate'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['w' + str(x.year)], axis=1)

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
   eecode  year  w2011  w2012  w2013  wage_rate
0       1  2012      7      8      9          8
1       1  2013      7      8      9          9
2       2  2011     20     25     25         20
3       2  2012     20     25     25         25
4       2  2013     20     25     25         25
```

Answer (score 2):

```
values = [ row['w%s'% row['year']] for key, row in df.iterrows() ]
df['wage_rate'] = values  # create the new columns
```

This solution is using an explicit loop, thus is likely slower than other pure-pandas solutions, but on the other hand it is simple and readable.

Answer (score 1):

you can rename columns names to be the same as year columns using replace

```
In [70]:
df.columns = [re.sub('w(?=\d+4$)' , '' , column ) for column in df.columns ]

In [80]:
df.columns
Out[80]:
Index([u'eecode', u'year', u'2011', u'2012', u'2013', u'wage_rate'], dtype='object')
```

then get the value using the following

```
df['wage_rate'] = df.apply(lambda x : x[str(x.year)] , axis = 1)
Out[79]:
eecode  year    2011    2012    2013    wage_rate
1       2012    7          8    9       8
1       2013    7          8    9       9
2       2011    20         25   25      20
2       2012    20         25   25      25
2       2013    20         25   25      25
```